# PHP parsing Wikipedia content, UTF8 hyphen

Tags: php, parsing, wikipedia

I'm currently trying to parse content from *de.wikipedia.org* with PHP.

After reading the pages with `file_get_contents(...)` and converting the received content with `utf8_decode(...)` from UTF8 to ISO-8859-1 the main part is displayed and saved correctly. Only some special characters like the "long hyphen" (**–**) are not being converted and getting display as **â€“** or **?**.

This hyphen seems to have to unicode-id 150 - how may i display it on ISO-8859-1?

Example: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/23_%E2%80%93_Nichts_ist_so_wie_es_scheint

Comment: You can't — it's not part of the [ISO-8859-1 character set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Codepage_layout) (although [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) does include it). You can transliterate it into a normal ASCII hyphen, however, as suggested by Niet. Or you could just change your program to output UTF-8 — it's 2014 now, why are you still using old 8-bit charsets like ISO-8859-1?

Answer (score 3):

Try using [`iconv`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) instead:

```
$iso = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $utf8);
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Already tried like every converting-function in PHP except this one. Thanks a lot!